# convert data type nvarchar to int and divide

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I am using SQL server 2016 and I have a table with 2 columns with data type nvarchar
the data in the first column '100~50' and the second column '50~25'
I want to  divide the first column to the second column and the final data is '2~2'

Comment: What happens if the division doesn't return an integer. I.e. `'75~50'`? Are you happy with the return value `1`?

Comment: instead of doing string splits in every bit of SQL, and if you can't change it to two fields, then split the two fields into computed columns

Answer (score 2):

Yuck.  You should really fix your data structure, so a single column doesn't have multiple values.  The following does the division -- calculating the components:

```
select cast(v1.col1_1 as int) / cast(v2.col2_1 as int) as new_col1,
       cast(v1.col2_2 as int) / cast(v2.col2_2 as int) as new_col2      
from t cross apply
     (values (left(t.col1, charindex('~', t.col1) - 1),
              left(t.col1, charindex('~', t.col2) - 1)
             )
     ) v1(col1_1, col2_1) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t1.col1, 1, len(v1.col1_1) + 1, ''),
              stuff(t2.col1, 1, len(v1.col2_1) + 1, '')
             )
     ) v2(col1_2, col2_2);
```

As I said before, multiple values should not be stored in a single string, so I don't recommend that you put this back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
select concat(cast(left(col1, charindex('~', col1) - 1) as int) / cast(right(col1, len(col1) - charindex('~', col1)) as int), '~', 
              cast(left(col2, charindex('~', col2) - 1) as int) / cast(right(col2, len(col2) - charindex('~', col2)) as int)
             )
from table t;
```

**EDIT** : You can avoid arithmetic error `divide by zero` by using `where` clause :

```
where right(col1, len(col1) - charindex('~', col1)) > 0 and
      right(col2, len(col2) - charindex('~', col2)) > 0
```

Comment: dont forget the case or you can divide by 0 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c24aa73355a0dd8fd3700aee59f015d9)

```
 select concat(val1,'~',val2) as col
from
(
select cast(substring(column1,0,charindex('~',column1)) as int)/cast(substring(column2,0,charindex('~',column2)) as int) as val1,
cast(substring(column1,charindex('~',column1)+1,len(column1)-charindex('~',column1)) as int)/cast(substring(column2,charindex('~',column2)+1,len(column2)-charindex('~',column2)) as int) as val2
from cte1
)X
```

OUTPUT:

```
col
2~2
```